# Reversing array elements in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, reverse

I am new to C and I have a problem. I need to reverse the elements of arrays in the following program. Can I get a very simple explanation of what I am doing wrong and how I could go on about fixing it?

Here's the output I get:

```
Enter number 0: 0
Enter number 1: 1
Enter number 2: 2
Enter number 3: 3
Enter number 4: 4
Enter number 5: 5
Enter number 6: 6
Enter number 7: 7
Element 0 is: 7
Element 1 is: 6
Element 2 is: 5
Element 3 is: 4
Element 4 is: 4
Element 5 is: 5
Element 6 is: 6
Element 7 is: 7
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int a[], int i)
{
    int j=7,b;
    for (i=0; i<=7; i++)
    {
        b=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=b;
        printf("Element %d is: %d\n", i,a[i]);
        j--;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[8];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    reverse(a, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i<=7/2`   or else it will reverse the whole thing again

Comment: This problem is simplest if you imagine solving it by hand: Swap the first and last, second and second last, etc. until you get to the middle. In code, keep _two_ indexes into the array. The first starts at 0 and the second at 7. Swap, then move the indexes inward (increment first, decrement second). Stop when the indexes meet (but think about what happens for both even and odd lists).  In general, think more. Code less.

Comment: Or just walk the array with two pointers until they meet/pass. [See it live](http://ideone.com/NiKkpN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid being misled, write the output after the reversal, not during it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int a[], int i)
{
    int j = 7, b;
    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        b = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = b;
        j--;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[8];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    reverse(a, 8);

    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        printf("Element %d is: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now you’ll notice the array isn’t changing at all. That’s because you’re swapping every element in the array twice: once to its reversed position, then back to its original position. To fix this, only loop over the first half the array, i.e. while `i < 4`.

It was probably also intended to make the second argument to `reverse` the length, so you should make use of that instead of hard-coding 7 or 4:

```
void reverse(int a[], int length)
{
    int i, j = length - 1, b;

    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        b = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = b;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "length" equal since it is not initialized? Would it be equal to 8?

Comment: Also, why do you subtract 1 from "length"? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Lethro: It’s not uninitialized; it’s a parameter. You pass it a value when calling the function, like how it’s called as `reverse(a, 8)` in `main`; 8 is the length. You’d subtract 1 from it because you want it to start out as the last index in the array, which is one less than the length (arrays starting at 0). (You were initializing it with 7 before and the length is 8.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also copy over the array in a new one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int a[], int i)
{
    int b[i];
    int j;

    for(j=0; j<i; j++){
        b[j] = a[i-1-j];
        printf("Element %d is: %d\n", j, b[j]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[8];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    reverse(a, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think a moment about the usefulness of `b[]` in this code. Why not just print `a[i-1-j]` on each pass? And `a[]` remains unchanged, which is the root of the initial problem, and this doesn't fix that.

Comment: I just wanted to show the option that you could access the elements in the reverse order without actually reversing the array, as well as build a reversed array without touching the original - just other options

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do it move through only half of the length of your array else you're reversing the array twice.

```
void reverse(int a[], int len)
{
    int i;
    int j=len-1,b;
    for(i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
        b=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=b;
        j--;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("Element %d is: %d\n", i,a[i]);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The Principe is simple. just stand at the middle of the table and reverse the elements as follow. so pose n is lent of the table. then the last element is n-1.

so you ave to reverse position t[0] and t[n-2]
reverse t[1] and t[n-3] and so on...

stop when you rich the middle of the table. try to code your self is better than for me giving you the code.
hope it helped.
```